# iPhone fetching ECID

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need a way in my app to uniquely identify each device. Is there a method to fetch the ECID of the device?

Comment: Did you ever find a method to fetch just the ECID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will UUID do for you? UUID is unique also. Moreover, I think ECID is not available in all devices (only in the newer hardwares). But, UUID is available in all devices.

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [device uniqueIdentifier];
```

Comment: Do you have any idea which devices don't have ECID?

Comment: @newenglander: Check out this post: http://www.iphoneheat.com/2010/04/iphone-ipad-ecid/
Mostly iPhone 3GS and later devices should have ECID (as Apple did not introduce it when it release iPhone 3G)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else needs this, try using the code from this github project, it worked for me, with some minor adjustments:

https://github.com/innoying/iOS-ecid

I believe if the device doesn't have an ECID (like the iOS Simulator for example), a null string is returned.

You'll need to link to the private framework IOKit. And of course refrain from submitting to Apple's App Store.

Comment: Hi, I need the ECID to generate the devices UDID, I already tryed to use IOS-ecid, but I cant make it to work. I tryed to make a function that returns a string, but I cant make it. May you post your code here?